# Divisibility by 11, How I get this part?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> My book makes a demonstration using the concept of congruence to show the divisibility by 11. But I don't understand the last part.

1. He stated with: 
   \begin{align}
   10\equiv 10 \mod11 \\
   1 \equiv 1 \mod11\\
   10^2\equiv1 \mod11 \to 10^{2n}\equiv1 \mod11
   \end{align}

and then, $10^{2n}*10 \equiv 0 \mod11$

2. Now for a number $n= n_{r}...n_5n_4n_3n_2n_1n_0$ wrote in base 10, we have that:

\begin{align}
n_0 \equiv n_0\mod11\\
10n_1+n_1 \equiv 0\mod11\\
10^2n_2\equiv n_2\mod11\\
10^3n_3+n_3 \equiv 0\mod11\\
...
\end{align}

3. Adding term by term we have this, the part that I don't understand:

> $n_1+n_3... \equiv n_0+n_2... \mod11$.

Because, When I sum the congruence I have this: 
$n_0+ (10a_1+a_1)+ 10^2a_2+ (10^3a_3+a_3)...\equiv a_0+a_2... \mod11$

How I get $n_1+n_3... \equiv n_0+n_2... \mod11$.??

Comment: See casting out elevens in the linked dupe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relations $\;10^{2k+1}a_{2k+1}+a_{2k+1}\equiv 0\mod 11$ simply means that 
$$10^{2k+1}a_{2k+1}\equiv-a_{2k+1}\mod 11,$$
so the relation becomes
$$a_0-a_1+a_2-a_3+\dotsm\equiv 0\iff a_0 +a_2 +\dotsm\equiv a_1+ a_3+\dotsm\mod 11.$$

Answer (score 3):

Some of your $n$'s changed into $a$'s.  The think to note is that $10 \equiv -1 \pmod{11}.$  So the coefficients on the odd-numbered $n$'s are all really $-1$ and you can move them to the other side, where the $-1$ changes into a $+1$.

Comment: Right. We’re interested in the alternating sum of the digits.